# .htaccess redirect to HTTPS not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This is how my current .htaccess looks like at the moment. Line 3 and 4 I took from another question at stackoverflow, and the rest simply removes the .php file extension. But the redirect to https part isn't working. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I just figured out that the problem is in my site's .conf file in the sites-enabled folder of apache. I need a separate  block for the :80 and :443 port, which I can't figure out how to do, but that's a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what I use to enforce https, hope it will be of use.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for redirect on https:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following code may Works.
Url:- home

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?page_slug=$0 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php?page_slug=$0 [QSA]
```

This is URL- page/new

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ page.php?page_slug=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ page.php?page_slug=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to redirect from http to https :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```